# How does an underscore change leaflet layer behavior?

Tags: leaflet

I'm not sure how the underscore affect leaflet layers.  I've seen it used to bind a popup to a sidebar click.  How does "map._layers" work?  I can't find anything in the documentation about using an underscore to select a layer differently.

```
geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            var id = layer._leaflet_id;
            var name = layer.feature.properties.NAME;
            var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates;
            var lng = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
            var lat = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1];

            // Populate features array and build autocomplete
            features.push({id: id, label: name, value: name, lat: lat, lng: lng});
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: features,
                minLength: 3,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    map.setView([ui.item.lat, ui.item.lng], 18);
                    map._layers[ui.item.id].openPopup();
                }
            });
            // Populate sidebar table with clickable feature links
            $("#featurelist table").append('<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="map._layers['+id+'].openPopup(); return false;">'+name+'</a></td></tr>');
            // Add features to zoom dropdown
            options += '<option value="' + lng + "," + lat + '", id="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>';
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The underscore means that `._layers` is a private property: that's why it's not documented or mentioned, and also why it's not a good idea to use. Use public methods like [eachLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) and variable references to layers instead.

Comment: I added larger context.  It's used within eachLayer. My bad.  Could you elaborate on "private property"?